# Producing an algebric equation from a graph

Tags: algebra

I'm writing a computer game and one of my game's objects must follow a movement path that is very similar to the following graph.

[image]

The bold lines are the Y and X axis. In order to be able to code this movement thought I need the algebric equation that translates to this graph. For example f(x) = x^2.

Is there any mathematic technique I could use to obtain the algebric from of this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can start from $\sin(x)$ which has a nice regular graph. To avoid negative values you can simply use the absolute value $|\sin(x)|$. This produces a graph similar to your but with constant height.

To decrease height as $x \to \infty$ we want to multiply that function by something that decrements. For example $\frac{1}{1+|x|}$ goes to $0$ as $x \to \infty$ and is symmetric. So [$\frac{1}{1+|x|}|\sin(x)|$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F%281%2B|x|%29%29|sin%28x%29|) is something similar to what you want with a maximum height of $1$.

If you multiply by a constant $A$ you "set" the maximum height to $A$. If you want to change the *width* of the bumps you can simply multiply the argument of the $\sin$ function, for example $\frac{A}{1+|x|}|\sin(2x)|$ will have maximum height $A$ and a width that is *half* the width of the normal $\sin$, while using $\sin(x/2)$ would produce a bump that is *twice* the width of the normal $\sin$.

See this [wolfram alpha's graph](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2F%281%2B|x|%29%29|sin%28x%2F2%29|) for an example result.

---

You can also change the degradation of height by setting a different power for the $|x|$. For example using $\frac{1}{1+x^2}$ you'd have a faster drop to $0$, while using $\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{|x|}}$ would produce a slower change in height.